# How does youtube javascript api communicate embed player in an iframe without restriction of same origin policy?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api, same-origin-policy, youtube-javascript-api

I found there is a strange thing about the youtube javascript api.The javascript api actually requests the player inside the iframe to do something. How can the api ignore the same origin policy? I have no idea about how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is [HTML5's postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) feature. It allows for sending data messages between two windows/frames across domains, currently supported on all major browsers. See [this demo](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/window-post-message.php) for an example (open the console to see messages getting passed).